# Highcharts es6 ScatterSeries: Uncaught TypeError: class heritage Jl is not an object or null

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6, charts, highcharts

I'm trying to follow the guide [here](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/installation-with-esm#including-a-product-package-es6-module) to create a minimal highcharts module/bundle to tree shake away unused code. But with this code:

```js
import Highcharts from 'highcharts/es-modules/Core/Globals.js';
import SVGRenderer from 'highcharts/es-modules/Core/Renderer/SVG/SVGRenderer.js';
import Chart from 'highcharts/es-modules/Core/Chart/Chart.js';
import ScatterSeries from 'highcharts/es-modules/Series/Scatter/ScatterSeries.js';

// options provided: https://gist.github.com/phun-ky/155d9db3b5d76a9b9bada94c63851ec3
import { getHighchartsOptions } from './lib/highcharts-options';

Highcharts.Renderer = SVGRenderer;
Highcharts.SVGRenderer = SVGRenderer;
Highcharts.Chart = Chart;
Highcharts.chart = Chart.chart;
// Chart created is a combinated LineSeries and ScatterSeries,
// but ScatterSeries is importing LineSeries (AFAIK)
Highcharts.ScatterSeries = ScatterSeries;

Highcharts.chart(
  chartElement,
  // https://gist.github.com/phun-ky/155d9db3b5d76a9b9bada94c63851ec3
  getHighchartsOptions(
    duration_average,
    durations_series
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
  ) as any
);
```

I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: class heritage Jl is not an object or null
    <anonymous> ScatterSeries.js:26
```

What am I doing wrong?